# Class reference member list initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

Can you tell me why output of that reference member of class different in different compilers?

```
  class B
  {
     int& aRef;
     public:
     B(int c):aRef(c){}

     void Print()
     {
         cout<<aRef<<endl;
     }
  };

  void f(int s)
  {
    int& lcRef=s;
    cout<<lcRef<<endl;
  }

 int main()
 {
    int x=100;
    B s(x);
    s.Print(); //ms c++ output : 3323244, gcc output :100
    f(x);   //ms c++ output : 100, gcc output:100
    return 0;
 }
```

And second question parameter of function `f(int s)` behaves same logic as contructor of class B's initialization?

Comment: You're saving a reference to a temporary (the `int c`parameter to the `B` constructor). Once the constructor is finished, it is no longer in scope, is destroyed and you then have a dangling reference. Accessing it thereafter is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
B(int c):aRef(c){}
```

This binds the reference to the constructor argument `c`. Since it's passed by value, it's destroyed when the constructor returns, leaving the reference dangling. Accessing it after the constructor returns gives undefined behaviour; in this case, it tries to access a lump of deallocated stack memory which may or may not still be accessible, and may or may not still contain the old value.

You want to pass by reference, to bind to the caller's variable:

```
B(int& c) : aRef(c) {}
```

Comment: gotcha so if change return type of f() to int& and just return lcRef without using cout, it will be undefined behaviour same as constructor right?

Comment: woow awsome now i can understand why passing by reference exist? damn what a programming language.. thanks

Comment: @DonCarleone: Yes, returning a reference to a local variable will also give undefined behaviour if anyone uses the reference. Compilers can usually warn about these problems, if you enable warnings.

Comment: I enabled warnings on ms c++ but it doesnt warm, i mean nothing warm for updated function f which returning a reference to a local variable.

Answer (score 4):

`f` function is correct and works as expected but here:

```
B(int c):aRef(c){}
```

You are basically assigning to `int& aRef` the address to a local automatic allocated variable (`c`). Now, references are safer than pointers but assigning a automatic allocated variable which goes out of scopes is one of the few cases that invalidates them.

The fact that the output is correct on GCC doesn't imply anything since that variable is not valid anymore ouside the constructor.

Comment: +1. One cannot even say with accuracy the output is "correct" on GCC, since the very term requires definitive conclusion, a condition utterly absent by the very nature of undefined (aka. lack of any definition) behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that *within* `f`, you are taking the reference to a parameter. This parameter is still valid when you print the content through the reference. For the constructor of `B`, you are **storing** the reference and when the constructor finishes, the referenced object goes out of scope, hence the reference becomes a dangling reference and using it becomes invalid. The output from GCC is just a coincidence, but it is not guaranteed.